# Chrome - refresh HTML page, sub-pages, sub-sub-pages etc. at once

Tags: html, google-chrome, polymer

I'm making an SPA website using Polymer. My main HTML page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/system.js/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        map:{
          traceur: '/bower_components/traceur/traceur.min.js'
        }
      });
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="import" href="/html/foobar-app.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <foobar-app></foobar-app>

  </body>
</html>
```

with `foobar-app` defined as:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
<link rel="import" href="/html/pages/all-territories.html">
<link rel="import" href="/html/pages/app-login.html">

<dom-module id="foobar-app">
  <template>
    <style></style>

    <iron-pages id="pages" selected="1">
      <app-login on-logged-in="onLoggedIn"></app-login>
      <all-territories></all-territories>
    </iron-pages>

    <iron-ajax
      url="http://api.foobar.com/data">
    </iron-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      Polymer({
        is: 'foobar-app',
        // ...
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When I make a change to `foobar-app`'s code everything works fine and updates if I refresh the page. But if I make a change to one of its sub-components or to one of the sub-component's own sub-components, the related html doesn't refresh and I have to manually browse to the related HTML file and press refresh. Else, only the top HTML file is refreshed (`foobar-app.html`).

How can I ask Chrome to refresh the current page and all its imports, sub-imports etc. whatever the deepness?

I've tried the following without success:

- Pressing `CTRL + MAJ + R` twice
- Pressing `CTRL + R` twice

Comment: Just to verify, if you open the page in a new incognito window it contains your new content correct?

Comment: @ShaBANG No, the problem occurs even in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the inspector for this page (right click, inspect).  Then right click on the refresh icon, finally select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" from the refresh drop down.

I have had problems with IFrames doing this, but never ajax calls; but this fixed it for me.